# jaspertreport v.6.1.1: font extension not working for international language

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm new to Jasper Report. I'm trying to display Thai characters in PDF using font extensions but for some reason the characters are not displayed. I've researched on this issue and followed the official documentation (http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/) but it didn't work.

I use TIBCO JasperSoft studio to do the design and everything is displayed correctly when I preview the design via JasperSoft studio. However, when I applied the generated jrxml file to my Java code the Thai characters were not displayed in PDF file. I also tried in Html file and everything worked just fine.

Following the official documentation to generate a PDF, i'm recommended to export the JAR file containing the TTF files, the jasperreports_extension.properties and fonts.xml files.

Please look at my code snippets

fontsfamily1445966397265.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
  <fontFamily name="tahoma">
    <normal>fonts/tahoma/Tahoma.ttf</normal>
    <bold>fonts/tahoma/tahomabd.ttf</bold>
    <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
    <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
    <exportFonts>
  <export key="xhtml">tahoma</export>
  <export key="html">tahoma</export>
</exportFonts>
```

jasperreports_extension.properties

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.simple.font.families=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.ireportfamily1445966397265=fonts/fontsfamily1445966397265.xml
```

Java Code

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JRXML_FILE);
String printFileName = JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(JASPER_FILE, params, conn);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(printFileName, PDF_FILE);
```

jrxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<!-- 2015-10-28T01:17:50 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="receipt" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="4eedbb89-b4f6-4469-9ab6-f642a1688cf7">
<property name="template.engine" value="tabular_template"/>
<style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="tahoma" fontSize="50" isBold="false"/>
<style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#CCCCCC" fontName="tahoma" fontSize="18" isBold="false"/>
<style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="tahoma" fontSize="14" isBold="false"/>
<style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="tahoma"/>
<style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="tahoma">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#EEEFF0"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<style name="Table">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#CACED0">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#D8D8D8"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<subDataset name="tableDataset" uuid="6590503c-ab84-4f89-80d9-38ac71dd1404">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter "/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <parameter name="customer_id" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT l.name, lbd.buy_type, lbd.buy_price, (lbd.buy_price - down_payment) AS debt FROM land l INNER JOIN land_buy_detail lbd ON l.id = lbd.land_id  WHERE lbd.customer_id = $P{customer_id}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="buy_type" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="buy_price" class="java.lang.Float"/>
    <field name="debt" class="java.lang.Float"/>
</subDataset>
<parameter name="customer_id" class="java.lang.Long">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{customer_id}]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT firstname, lastname, address, tel FROM customer WHERE id = $P{customer_id}]]>
</queryString>
<field name="firstname" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="lastname" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="tel" class="java.lang.String"/>
<title>
    <band height="357" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="90" width="84" height="25" uuid="57aed2b1-4f4e-40a3-a6ad-54dae8dd4c5a">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement>
                <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Bill to:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="80" width="556" height="1" uuid="806ce5df-1219-4876-ae0c-ca7405b1f246">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
        </line>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="415" y="10" width="50" height="20" uuid="0f86baff-6386-4f3f-b3fe-2388707babe8"/>
            <box rightPadding="4"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Date:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
            <reportElement x="465" y="10" width="84" height="20" uuid="bb10dbe1-0a4f-4722-9953-c163b63cf979"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <image hAlign="Center">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="65" height="60" uuid="94883631-a913-43e2-b182-ab8d77d0181e"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["invoice_logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
            <reportElement x="465" y="30" width="84" height="20" uuid="3836ce65-eca3-4cad-a6de-b1818def0a2b"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["INV0001"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="415" y="30" width="50" height="20" uuid="0b3f9342-da78-4cfa-9fc5-2301c4749678"/>
            <box rightPadding="4"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Invoice:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="95" y="0" width="205" height="25" uuid="e622555d-198b-4ccd-a4a1-c59c53304058">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement>
                <font size="19" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[BP Property]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="95" y="55" width="205" height="15" uuid="b8cc42fd-b569-497d-834d-7e854040ad18"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="tahoma"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[08-19595-240]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="95" y="25" width="205" height="15" uuid="c226e44d-3bb5-4145-b0b3-903bf1d79fde"/>
            <textElement markup="none">
                <font fontName="tahoma" size="11" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[1174 ถ. เพชรเกษม อ. หาดใหญ่]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="95" y="40" width="205" height="15" uuid="b96f7183-44f8-43ad-ba60-43d8fbf50b6e"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="tahoma"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[ต. หาดใหญ่ จ. สงขลา  90110]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="115" width="120" height="15" uuid="0e5185a4-3292-4051-927f-7e07f549bceb"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new String($F{firstname} + " " + $F{lastname})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="130" width="120" height="15" uuid="0925d7fe-e543-4225-b44e-ff1828d6cb8a"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="145" width="120" height="15" uuid="199db39e-5210-4d3a-a0c5-baf4543d9d49"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tel}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="0" y="166" width="555" height="130" uuid="b8e9c2ed-feb3-408c-b9be-6aebbeb6af52"/>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataset" uuid="6ea978fd-ffe0-40bb-84a7-f09b1f220cfa">
                    <datasetParameter name="customer_id">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{customer_id}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="190" uuid="06d1364f-8060-496c-ac0c-b44946e09dd0">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement key="" style="Column header" x="0" y="0" width="190" height="30" forecolor="#000000" uuid="93321529-b12d-4528-8316-4e6e94a6c476">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <box leftPadding="2"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="tahoma" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[รายการ]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Detail" x="0" y="0" width="190" height="30" uuid="4be9692f-e0bf-4a89-9f21-b579d46c9adf">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <box leftPadding="2"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="tahoma" size="12"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["   " + $F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="25357c6d-7a1a-4bcb-ac60-8d18805b681c">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" forecolor="#000000" uuid="c8f288aa-8d2e-48ce-8ee7-d710740d7b52"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="tahoma" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[ประเภท]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Detail" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="6735552d-0796-499f-af74-e308260bc5e0"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="tahoma" size="12"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{buy_type}.equals("C")) ? "   สด" : "   ผ่อน"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="120" uuid="18cfa391-26d8-4a47-8e88-a7d1bef16d74">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement key="" style="Column header" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" forecolor="#000000" uuid="fc75656e-008d-47b4-ab25-2cdb62acb876"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="tahoma" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[ราคาซื้อ]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Detail" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" uuid="db5ac821-df67-42ec-8f12-c3cbce27a8fd"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="tahoma" size="12"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["   " + $F{buy_price}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="155" uuid="c192f0f1-d7f3-4362-8149-f9d592cdac30">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement key="" style="Column header" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="155" height="30" forecolor="#000000" uuid="2c3771ca-3b46-4bae-837b-88fac22baff7"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="tahoma" size="12" isBold="false"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[ยอดคงค้าง]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                        <textField pattern="#,###.##">
                            <reportElement style="Detail" x="10" y="0" width="145" height="30" uuid="94659f20-5913-48a2-b64c-683d0584936c"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="12"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{debt}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="290" width="556" height="30" backcolor="#E6E8E9" uuid="36aa233d-4305-48e6-974a-1bbf89bb3c8f"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="tahoma" size="9" isItalic="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[THANKYOU FOR YOUR BUSINESS]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<summary>
    <band height="293" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
    </band>
</summary>
```

I'm sure that the JAR file is in my Maven classpath.

I'm using Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1.

Comment: There is an additional jar jasperreports fonts. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports-fonts/6.0.0 . Do you have that on the classpath as well?

Comment: thanks for your response. yes it's in my classpath but it's version 6.0.0 not 6.1.1. I don't think it matters in this case.

Comment: No it doesn't since there is no version 6.1.1. If you open the PDF in adobe acrobat, you should be able to see somewhere what fonts are embedded in the PDF. I don't know the exact menu item. Is the font you expect actually embedded in the generated PDF?

Comment: Yea, I set the pdfEmbedded property to true.

Comment: That's not what I asked at all.

Comment: sorry misread. Yes it is embedded in the generated PDF.

Tahoma
TrueType(CID)
Encoding: Identity-H
Embedded subset

Comment: I solved the issue.  I just forgot to point JASPER_FILE variable to the right file. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. I just forgot to point JASPER_FILE variable to the right file. This solution for displaying international characters already worked :)